# Google Maps Javascript API, Direction Update with Geolocation Move

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created simple app that, get users current position and the destination and set direction through the google map javascript api.

Sample code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'),
            mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var lat = position.coords.latitude; //get the current position
var lon = position.coords.longitude;

var request = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon), //set the position
    destination: "colombo", //set the destination
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); //set the direction in google map
    }
});
```

**Question:** 
Now i want to update the direction dynamically based on current location when user move the device.  ( like android google maps app )

Is google api support that kind of stuff.
Is there anyway to do it without re-run the js again.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222330/geolocation-moving-only-google-maps-marker-without-reload-the-map

Comment: yes. this helps. search like 3 hours google didn't found this post. even in stackoverflow suggestions. ( may be wrong keywords ) thanks.